# How can I get the innerHTML of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments

I want to pass the innerHTML of a clicked button to the onClick method in React. How can I do that? Please note, I am not asking about the arrow notation; I am asking how to get the innerHTML of the button so that I can pass it as an argument.

This is how I am creating the buttons:

```
var buttons = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    buttons.push(
      <button onClick={() => props.handleClick(this.correctAnswers, this.innerHTML)}>
        {currentAnswers[i]}
      </button>
    )
  }
        return <div >{buttons}</div>;}
```

and this is my onClick method

```
 handleClick(correctAnswers, inner) {
   alert(correctAnswers)
   alert(inner)

 }
```

The handleClick() doesn't do anything yet. I'm just trying to pass in the values for now. alert(inner) is undefined.
Thanks

Comment: While this is possible to fix by using a `function` instead, and saving the `this` context from the outer scope with something like `that = this`, referencing the clicked element's `innerHTML` directly in the handler is pretty weird to do - referencing `currentAnswers[i]` would make more sense, to start with, eg ``() => props.handleClick(this.correctAnswers, currentAnswers[i])``

Comment: OK. Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks.
Can you remove the "duplicate" from this post? Thanks.

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. You're using an arrow function when you wanted to capture the new `this` context

Comment: The `onClick` passes the event itself, so: `<button onClick={(e) => props.handleClick(this.correctAnswers, e.target.innerHTML)}>`

Comment: No. Those are completely different questions. I wasn't asking about the arrow function or about this. I was asking about using the innerHTML of a button as an argument.